# Google Cloud Platform VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, google-cloud-platform, ikev2

Is there a way to change the lifetime in seconds for Phase 1 and Phase 2 of Ipsec?  I am trying to connect to a Cisco ASA 5550 at a customer site and their lifetime in seconds setting is 86,400(Phase 1) and 28,800(Phase 2).  These need to match and I cannot adjust it on the Cisco side as their IT department will not alter it.  From what I can find on the GCP the default settings are 36,000 and 10,800 and I cannot find any way to change this... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, with IKEv1 the configuration must match at both ends, and this is not configurable on the Google side. As a result, if you're not able to [change the configuration of the peer](https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithCiscoASA.pdf), unfortunately you won't be able to [configure Cloud VPN for use](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns#set_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway).